# A la recherche d’un poème sur l’alphabet, avec un jeu de mots sur “oeuf”

Tags: littérature, poésie

Il me semble que j’ai lu ce poème plusieurs fois dans mes cours de français. Malheureusement, je n’arrive pas à le trouver sur internet.

Les mots du poème n’ont rien a avoir avec l’alphabet, mais en le lisant, ça sonne comme si on disait l’alphabet. Le poème saute aussi la lettre “f”, mais dans le poème ou il devrait apparaître il y a le mot “oeuf”, avec un jeu de mot sur entendu car le “f” d’oeuf est silencieux. Il me semble aussi que le poème commence avec “abeille” (pour les lettres ab de l’alphabet), mais cette mémoire est moins claire que celle d'œuf.

Je m’excuse (et apprécierai beaucoup des corrections pour) mes erreurs de français.

---

I think I’ve read this poem several times in my french classes. Unfortunately I haven’t been able to find it online

The words of the poem don’t have anything to do with the alphabet, but when you read it, it sounds like you’re saying the alphabet. The poem skips the letter “f”, but at the point in the poem where it should appear there is the word “oeuf” (en: egg), with a play on words since the f is silent. I also believe that the poem starts with “abeille” (en: bee) (for the letters ab in the alphabet), but I’m less sure of that than the play on words with “oeuf.

My apologies for the mistakes I’ve made in the French portion, I would certainly appreciate any corrections or advice you have concerning my French usage/spelling/grammar/etc...

Comment: Is it similar to what's on [this page](http://marenostrum83.blogspot.com/2006_02_01_archive.html)? "ah baie c'est dé oeufs ève geai hache y-gît cas aile aime haine eau pet cul air est-ce thé ? hue vais double verre rixe îles grecques cèdent."

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the idea. Although the version I remember definitely had nothing for "f" whereas this version includes "ève" to that effect

Comment: It would be *oeufs* [ø] plural for the letter "e," not "f," right?  In the singular, the [f] is pronounced in *oeuf* [œf], but the plural does not.  Maybe that is the trick you're remembering?